# I want my buttons (white color) to green if the user picks the correct answer and red if wrong, then the correct one in green

Tags: flutter, dart

```
RaisedButton (
  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 8.0, 10.0, 8.0),
  elevation: 8.0,
  color: butColor ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      if (quiz.choices[questionNumber][0] == quiz.correctAnswers[questionNumber]){
        finalScore = finalScore + 4;
        butColor = true;

      }else{
        debugPrint("Wrong");
        butColor = false;
      }

    });
  },
  child: Text(quiz.choices[questionNumber][0],
  style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 22.0,
    fontFamily: "AlegreyaSans",
    color: Colors.black
  ),),
),
```

[image: This is what I get when I try the above code]

I have bool variable `butColor` set to `false` too.

When I try setting the buttons color to white and doing the switch statement inside the if else, I still get just white color buttons.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed explanation @Phil Dubem

Comment: I want  my buttons to have 3 colors, one active and one if the if else statement is correct and one if false @T.TSage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set an Enum and according to the value change the color of the button. Just create a variable to hold the enum value. I have used buttonStatus variable here and initialize it to ButtonStatus.Unanswered

```
 enum ButtonStatus{Unanswered,CorrectAnswer,WrongAnswer}

    Color getButtonColor (ButtonStatus status) {
      switch (status) {
        case ButtonStatus.Unanswered: {
          return Colors.white;
        }
        break;
        case ButtonStatus.CorrectAnswer: {
          return Colors.green;
        }
        break;
        case ButtonStatus.WrongAnswer: {
          return Colors.red;
        }
        break;

        default: {
          return Colors.white;
       }
     }
   }
```

And then your code will be updated as follows

```
RaisedButton (
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 8.0, 10.0, 8.0),
    elevation: 8.0,
    color: getButtonColor(buttonStatus),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
    onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
            if (quiz.choices[questionNumber][0] == 
                 quiz.correctAnswers[questionNumber]){
                    finalScore = finalScore + 4;
                    buttonStatus = ButtonStatus.CorrectAnswer;
                 }else{
                    debugPrint("Wrong");
                    buttonStatus = ButtonStatus.WrongAnswer
                }
            });
           },
    child: Text(quiz.choices[questionNumber][0],
               style: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 22.0,
               fontFamily: "AlegreyaSans",
               color: Colors.black
             ),
         ),
     ),
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I had to edit your switch statement , aside that, it worked perfectly fine for what I asked. Thanks a lot