# How to make separate buttons have different colors

Tags: flutter, dart

Please this is a follow up to the answer i got here [Previous Question Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61690729/i-want-my-buttons-white-color-to-green-if-the-user-picks-the-correct-answer-an). I applied the answer, but my issue is I have 4 different buttons and on tapping the correct one, all 4 buttons go green and all go red when wrong. What i want is when correct, it goes green (only correct button) and when wrong only the one tapped goes red, with only the correct one going green. Am a newbie in flutter.

This is the answer I got

Initialized Enum

```dart
 enum ButtonStatus{Unanswered,CorrectAnswer,WrongAnswer}

    Color getButtonColor (ButtonStatus status) {
      switch (status) {
        case ButtonStatus.Unanswered: {
          return Colors.white;
        }
        break;
        case ButtonStatus.CorrectAnswer: {
          return Colors.green;
        }
        break;
        case ButtonStatus.WrongAnswer: {
          return Colors.red;
        }
        break;

        default: {
          return Colors.white;
       }
     }
   }

var buttonStatus = ButtonStatus.Unanswered;
```

and codes for button

```dart
RaisedButton (
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 8.0, 10.0, 8.0),
    elevation: 8.0,
    color: getButtonColor(buttonStatus),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
    onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
            if (quiz.choices[questionNumber][0] == 
                 quiz.correctAnswers[questionNumber]){
                    finalScore = finalScore + 4;
                    buttonStatus = ButtonStatus.CorrectAnswer;
                 }else{
                    debugPrint("Wrong");
                    buttonStatus = ButtonStatus.WrongAnswer
                }
            });
           },
    child: Text(quiz.choices[questionNumber][0],
               style: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 22.0,
               fontFamily: "AlegreyaSans",
               color: Colors.black
             ),
         ),
     ),
```

[See Buttons Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIb4f.png)

Comment: Can you post your updated code here?

Comment: @shubham I've added the codes here, I have 4 of those buttons exacly like that

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are using the same buttonStatus variable for all the four-button and hence the effect is seen in all buttons.

To fix this either you can have a map or a list of buttonStatus and assign each button a different status.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it's a quiz game where all four buttons have different options and only one is correct.

Comment: yeah, I get it, but here buttonStatus is just used to update the UI, User can click on any button and needs to know the status of only that button not the rest. So you need to update the UI according to buttonStatus related to that button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by having an array for storing the status of each button

Something like..

```
var a = [ButtonStatus.Unanswered, ButtonStatus.Unanswered, ButtonStatus.Unanswered, ButtonStatus.Unanswered];
```

And.. whenever user taps on a particular button change the corresponding element in the array.

Like..if user taps on 2nd button

```
a[1] = ButtonStatus.CorrectAnswer
```

Note sure if it is the same what you want..but you can do something like this.